# Bitcoinj Is not syncing with Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, bitcoin, bitcoinj

My Android app is not syncing to the blockchain, but when I used the bitcoinj libarary on my PC it worked fine.
Note: Both programs start with `walletAppKit.setBlockingStartup(false).startAsync().awaitRunning()` when the kit is complete and the app calls this on the `onCreate` method and has sufficient permissions such as read/write and internet. The test device is also physical and not an emulator.
I logged both programs using

```
" File Directory:${walletAppKit.directory()}\nTransactions:\n"
try {
for(x in walletAppKit.wallet().transactionsByTime){
str+="${x.txId}\n"
}

    str+="Peer # and running:${walletAppKit.peerGroup().numConnectedPeers()} ${walletAppKit.peerGroup().isRunning}\n"
    str+="Chain Height: ${walletAppKit.chain().chainHead.height}\n"
    str+="Balance: ${walletAppKit.wallet().balance.toPlainString() } BTC Received: ${walletAppKit.wallet().totalReceived.toPlainString() } BTC Sent: ${walletAppKit.wallet().totalSent.toPlainString() } BTC\n"
    str+="Directory Status: ${walletAppKit.directory().totalSpace} bytes\n Can Read File?:${walletAppKit.directory().canRead()} Can Write File?:${walletAppKit.directory().canWrite()}"
```

Here is the logging output screenshots
[image]
[image]

You'll notice that the one with TX-IDS is running on my laptop and has a way bigger block amount than the one running on the phone, how can I get this synced up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the kotlin bitcoin kit provided by [horizontal systems](https://github.com/horizontalsystems/bitcoin-kit-android) on github. Use `implementation 'com.github.horizontalsystems:bitcoin-kit-android:694d681f3e'` in your `gradle module` and in your project module add `mavenCentral()`in the buildscript branch:

`buildscript {`

`repositories {`

`other stuff`

`mavenCentral()`

`}`

`dependencies {`

`}`

`}`

Then in the `allprojects` brackets place `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }` in the `repositories` brackets:

`allprojects{`

`repositories{`

`*other stuff*`

`maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }`

`}`

`}`